# Why does the inner loop range make a difference in the way this problem is solved?

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

> Write a static method `printNumbers` that takes an integer max as an argument and prints out all perfect numbers that are less than or equal to max.

At first, I kept getting the wrong answer because the inner loop was set to j < max before I changed it to j < i. However, I don't understand why that range would matter, because wouldn't `i % j != 0` anyway, even if the range of j were to be larger?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {   
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            sum += j;
        }
    }
    if (sum == i) {
        System.out.print(sum + " ");
    }
}
```

If I changed the inner loop `j < max`, then `printNumbers(6)` gives both 1 and 6, but `printNumbers(500)` gives only 1 and no other number.

Comment: The difference is when `j == i`, because `i % j` *is* 0 when that happens

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: If j is allowed to climb beyond i, e.g. to max, then it will be larger than i during the loop. And also hit i once per iteration, yielding modulo 0. However, note that you are doing i mod j, not the other way around. 10 mod 5 is 0 as well, as it is for every divisor. So you are summing up all the divisors of i per iteration.

Comment: E.g., 1 % 1 == 0 would happen with `j < max` but not with `j < i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `j < max` in the inner loop, then when `j = i`, `i % j == 0` returns `true` and skews your result.
This is a good example of a mathematical error to watch out for in coding.

Comment: I see, so printNumbers(500) wouldn't return 6 as an option, nor 28 or 496 because the sum would have been incremented by the value when j = i, which is what you mean by skewing the result, right?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean. So, `sum == i` will erroneously return false for that `i` (6, 28, 496).